# Which of the following statements is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

(Q) is false since unitary matrix has modulus 1 eigenvalues.
I think (P) is true but I am not sure how to Prove or Disprove this.
Please suggest?

Comment: You can show directly that the $im(M)=ker(M^*)^\perp$. For $Q$, let $x$ be an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, what would be $<Mx,Mx>$?

Comment: What is R(M)? row space of M?

Comment: I think this question was asked in GATE 16.

Answer (score 1):

[Hint] :Column space (Range space) is orthogonal to left null space. and eigenvalues of unitary matrix is $1$.

[image: Four Fundametal subspaces]